# How to check for corrupt exe files using python?

Tags: exe, runner

Is there any way to find corrupt exe from many exe's through python, or any existing exe runner module? I want to check the exit status of a exe whether a file is executed perfectly or ended up with an error.

Like the program below for testing corrupt zip:

```
import os
import sys
import zipfile

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = sys.argv[1:]


print "Testing zip file: %s" % args[0]

the_zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(args[0])
ret = the_zip_file.testzip()

if ret is not None:
    print "First bad file in zip: %s" % ret
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    print "Zip file is good."
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Defining "corrupt" could help... "executed perfectly" is hard to quantify with code - especially for something beyond basic command line tools like findstr.exe.

Comment: Even "good" exe can end with an error status. As Alexei said, you must define "corrupt"!